# How to concatenate string in single quotation in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

syntax error at BCHF_VOU_NUM +' '+ BCHF_VOU_DTE

```
set @m_sql =  'Select distinct BCHF_VOU_NUM, BCHF_VOU_DTE, BCHF_E_AMT, NACD_DES, 
(BCHF_VOU_NUM +' '+ BCHF_VOU_DTE +' '+BCHF_E_AMT +' '+NACD_DES) as name,
dbo.E_DOC_NUM_2_CHEQUE_NO(BCHF_E_DOC_NUM) FROM ' + @ParaCoCode + '..BCH' + @ParaBatchNo  +   ' abc inner join v_AnalysisCode on BCHF_E_ANA_CDE1 = ANACode inner join  
Project_TR_TP_COM_Test.dbo.FlexAccount zz ON zz.CurrentAccountID = (Select 
CurrentAccountID from Batch where'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To escape a single quote in SQL, you have to use the same character twice. `''` will be substituted as one single quote in your concatenated string.